# Question about the definition of faithful functors

Tags: category-theory, functors

In TOM LEINSTER's [Basic Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf), Page 25, it says
[image]

I got very confused here. Doesn't the definition of *injective* says for distinct $f_1, f_2$ we have $F(f_1)\neq F(f_2)$? Why this is false? I think I must have some misunderstandings about the definition. Can anyone explain this for me and give some concrete examples?

Comment: If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are distinct maps *with the same domain and codomain*, then $F(f_1) \neq F(f_2)$.

Comment: Could you please give a concrete example?

Comment: @FFjet Let $G$ and $H$ be two distinct groups with underlying set equal to $S = \{ a , b \}$ (for example take $a$ to be the identity in $G$ and $b$ the identity in $H$). The identity morphisms $1_G$ and $1_H$ in the category of groups both map to the identity morphism $1_S$ in the category of sets under the forgetful functor from groups to sets, yet they are distinct morphisms in the category of groups, indeed they don't even have the same source and target!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be distinct morphisms. Then there must be objects $A_1,A_1',A_2,A_2'$ in $\mathcal A$ such that $f_1\in\mathcal A(A_1,A_1')$ and $f_2\in\mathcal A(A_2,A_2')$. Faithfulness of $F$ implies that if $A_1=A_2$ and $A_1'=A_2'$, we must have $F(f_1)\neq F(f_2)$.

But if $A_1\neq A_2$ or $A_1'\neq A_2'$ we can have that $F(f_1)=F(f_2)$ even though $F$ is faithful. For instance let $\mathcal A$ have two objects, $A_1,A_2$ and let the identity morphisms $1_{A_1}$ and $1_{A_2}$ be the only morphisms in $\mathcal A$. Fix an object $B\in\mathcal B$. We define $F:\mathcal A\to\mathcal B$ by $F(A_1)=F(A_2)=B$, and $F(1_{A_1})=1_{B}=F(1_{A_2})$. So we have that $F(1_{A_1})=F(1_{A_2})$ even though $1_{A_1}\neq 1_{A_2}$. Nevertheless, because the homsets $\mathcal A(A_i,A_j)$ for $i,j=1,2$ are either empty or a singleton set, we have that $\mathcal A(A_i,A_j)\to \mathcal B(F(A_i),F(A_j)), f\mapsto F(f)$ is injective, hence $F$ is faithful.

Comment: Thanks! Now it is clear.